# Jdeps command reporting package as found and then the same package as not found

Tags: java, jdeps

The jdeps command that I am running is "jdeps -cp '*classpath*' -R '*path-to-package*'". The following is the output: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gadDg.png)

Apologies for the link. SO won't let me embed an image.